# Sharing Browser Links between PC and Phone

Tags: browser, sync, bookmarks

I'm starting a wiki to compile a short list of browsers, apps, extensions, etc. that allow users to easily link or bookmark webpages between their PC and phone. This is ultimately just a "best apps" question, so answers should be made CW. I placed an answer below. Any other suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running Android 4.0+, just use Google Chrome both on [PC](http://www.google.com/chrome) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome), and associate it with the same Google account. This allows you to sync your browsers so that you can see open tabs from both locations on all devices. You can even have multiple PCs/OSs synced, just use the same Google account.

> "Sign in to Chrome to sync your open tabs, bookmarks, passwords, and omnibox data from your computer to your phone or tablet.  Pick up right where you left off."

Comment: I enjoy this feature. If it wasn't limited to Android 4.0+, it would be perfect.

Comment: Does this feature still exist? I have Android 7 and use Chrome signed into same account on my phone and my Macbook. I can't find any option to share a link or tab from phone to desktop browser though.

Comment: Ah... I can open 'History' in Chrome desktop then go to "Tabs from other devices" and find links from Chrome on the phone there

Answer (score 8):

No-one seems to have said Pushbullet yet; it's trivially easy to share a webpage to Pushbullet from a phone and push it to the Windows/Mac app or Chrome extension, and the Chrome extension only needs 2 clicks to share any link, whether it's the page you're on or a link you can right-click.

Comment: AirDroid works more consistently for me. PushBullet (at least with Android) seems to not connect. Also AirDroid does mirroring too, and i think the notification actions are richer.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for bookmark sync for my Android phone too and initially considered [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) but for some reason none of two available mobile clients worked properly (2.3.6).

I ended up registering and using service [diigo.com](http://www.diigo.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Google Keep, nothing beats it. Pretty instant. The above fly-by-night apps (except for some, like Pocket and browser addons) are un-dependable.

Comment: Look like there's 2 Google keep extension: "[Google Keep](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki?hl=fr)" and "[Google Keep Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi/related)". I guess you choose the one with the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

These are all the ones I've used.

Both ways:

- Chrome sync (current open tabs and bookmarks, chrome with chrome for android)
- Firefox sync (current open tabs and bookmarks, firefox with firefox beta)
- Opera link (bookmarks only, opera with opera mini)
- Pocket (bookmarklet/share with)

One way (desktop to phone only):

- Chrome to phone
- Fox to phone

Answer (score 1):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) is able to exchange the contents of the clipboard over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can always use social bookmarking and sync with your existing bookmarks. Look into [Papaly](https://www.papaly.com/) for easy to use user interface. Just as long as you have the internet on your Android devices, you'll be able to look at all your bookmarks anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I create a QR code from Edge, transport to Android, read it with Lens.