# What are some use-cases for FireFox|Chrome-to-Phone?

Tags: sync, browser-add-ons, google-chrome-to-phone

According to [FoxToPhone](http://www.foxtophone.com/about/) (presumable, ChrometoPhone is similar)

you can

- Send current page with address bar button
- Right click on any link/image to send to your Android phone
- Highlight any text and right click to send to the clipboard in your phone (Max. 1024 chars)
- Click on market:, smsto: and tel: links to open them in your phone
- Best of all it’s free and open source

mmmmm. nice. Okay. It's installed in FireFox and on my phone. I highlight text, right-click, send to phone. Blammo! It's on my phone's clipboard!

But..... what are the uses for this? WHEN does anybody need to send a block of text TO THE PHONE'S CLIPBOARD?

If anything, I'd want this the other way around -- when browsing a page in Dolphin, I'd rather read in on my desktop later, or something.

What do y'all use this for?

---

See also: [Sharing Browser Links between PC and Phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/sharing-browser-links-between-pc-and-phone)

Comment: This is subjective/asking for a list of things.  Can you make this a CW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of one nasty block of text off the top of my head: your bit.ly key that you have to provide to 3rd party applications (i.e. Twitter clients).  It's like a 20+ random character string.  So any other long "key" like string would be a good reason to blast it from your desktop.

Images: maybe you found a cool image for a desktop background?

Answer (score 8):

Maps. Setting up directions and alternate routes in Google Maps is much easier with a full-fledged web client. Then, when I have what I need, I can send it to my phone.

Comment: Yep. It's a lot easier (and faster) to search and set up waypoints for directions on Google Maps when you have a keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Installing new apps. I have a Firefox keyword bookmark to [androlib.com](http://www.androlib.com/), so if I want to install an app, I just type e.g. "al newsrob", which starts a search query on AndroLib, then select one of the hits, and click on the market:// link there. Chrome2Phone on the device then launches this URL in the browser, which immediately causes the market installer for that app to appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can also type "tel:12345" into your browser's address bar (FoxToPhone, not sure about Chrome2Phone) to make the device present the dial screen with that number already entered, so you just have to pick it up.

(No, I don't actually use that, but it's a nice demonstration. ;) )

Comment: Interesting trick... doesn't work with Chrome, unless there's a hack for it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome to Phone also allows you to send phone numbers to your device.  Highlight the phone number, click the Chrome to Phone extension button, and wham, it's open in the dialer on your device.  Really handy when you've been researching businesses online and now want to call one of them.

I'm not sure if FoxToPhone supports this too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case gmail is filtered at work.

So to send an email I only have my mobile as an option. I type up the email on the desktop and use foxtophone to put it on the clipboard. Beats scraping it out on the touchscreen!