# Can I sync Firefox bookmarks with Android?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox-for-android

Is there any way to sync my Firefox bookmarks with Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Fennec (Firefox mobile) will have this feature, but it is currently only in alpha. You can get a copy of the alpha [here](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/m/alpha).  Note that you'll need about 40mb+ of internal storage space free to install it.

Comment: Firefox mobile does support this natively now, via the Mozilla Sync service (built-in to mobile, and a free add-in for the desktop Firefox). Note, that it has been massively slimmed down since the early betas, the current Firefox 4 beta 3, only needs about 6mb and is enabled for app2SD, it's available in the Android Market http://www.appbrain.com/app/mozilla-firefox-web-browser/org.mozilla.firefox

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a FireFox extension that bring bookmarks to your phone permanently. There are a few suggestions in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1727/15) question but they are designed more for sending links on a one-time basis. 
Getting the Del.icio.us FireFox [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615/) and the Del.icio.us add-on for the Android dolphin browser might be the best bet. (I knew I saw this somewhere on here... props to this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/sharing-browser-links-between-pc-and-phone/1761#1761) which mentions Del.icio.us for Android.)

Answer (score 3):

[Xmarks Premium](http://buy.xmarks.com/premium.php) allows to synchronize all bookmarks between different PCs (supports Chrome, Firefox and more) and different mobile phones/tablet (Android, iPhone, Blackberry) for 12$/year.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a HTC phone and Windows, then HTC sync will do this.