# Any way to sync Bookmarks between Android and Blackberry?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, blackberry

Is there any way to sync my Bookmarks between my BlackBerry Torch and My Samsung Tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer copied from Drake in [Can I sync Firefox bookmarks with Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/can-i-sync-firefox-bookmarks-with-android)*

> [Xmarks Premium](http://buy.xmarks.com/premium.php) allows to synchronize all bookmarks between
>   different PCs (supports Chrome, Firefox and more) and different mobile
>   phones/tablet (Android, iPhone, Blackberry) for 12$/year.

**Edit #1:** If you're looking for a FREE alternative, you can try [Dolphin browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) (it's available for both Android and Blackberry). Dolphin lets you [sync bookmarks](http://dolphin-browser.com/2012/07/dolphin-v8-6-synced-and-connected/).

Comment: This is an option, thanks but are there any free alternatives arround too?

Comment: @r4d1um See my Edit #1

Comment: Dolphin is only available for "BlackBerry Playbook" so i need to choose option 1.

Comment: I just found an other alternative, use firefox on PC and Android and BerrySync on my BlackBerry (FREE). But i will try your solution aswell.