# How to create a url link file in Android?

Tags: files, url

In windows, we can create a .url file to link to a website. How can I do this on Android? I want to send some links to my Android device from my PC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you would like to achieve.

If you want to just send a link from your computer to your Android device you have several possibilities:

- Send an email to yourself containing the URL. Of course you need to have that email account synched on your Android phone. Then open the mail there and click on the link. Admittedly, this is a not very elegant approach
- Another approach is to use [Chrome2Phone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/). It consists of a mobile app and a Google [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco) that adds a button to your Chrome browser. By clicking on that button, a link of the currently open tab will be sent to your mobile phone and directly opened there on the browser. Here's a Youtube video that explains how to set it up: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQb243niMlg

If you want to have links on your Android homescreen, you may create bookmarks in your Android Browser and then add them by long-pressing on the homescreen, then choosing "Shortcuts" followed by "Bookmark"

Comment: Cannot run chrome2phone in China. the appspot site has been blocked by GFW

Answer (score 0):

Numerous [alternative solutions here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/sharing-browser-links-between-pc-and-phone).

Answer (score 0):

In Jelly Bean, create links as follows:

1. Create a Bookmark in your browser.
2. Go into apps list and click widgets tab.
3. Scroll to Bookmarks widget and press and hold, then drop on home screen where desired.
4. When asked, select browser bookmark to associate with
   bookmark widget.

Works on Atrix2, YMMV.

Comment: Yeah -- but that creates a shortcut on the homescreen. OP wants to share a link to his PC, which doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice solution I use daily is [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro). Several apps support it directly, and for others it's available via the "Share" menu. You can think of that like "bookmarks in the cloud".

On the PC, you can access your "Pocket bookmarks" via their web service using any browser, or use the Pocket addon (available e.g. [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/read-it-later/)). I cannot think of an easier way to share links between the two devices!