# Share Links via Bluetooth without it being converted to HTML?

Tags: bluetooth, data-transfer

I'm often browsing articles on my phone and when something *piques* my interest, I normally want to "share" it over to my computer to read it a little better or sometimes, just because the website wasn't optimized for mobile viewing.

What I've been doing as of late, is sharing the URL from the ICS browser via bluetooth. This would have worked well but I would like it **NOT** to create **.html** files for every link I send. Here's an example of an HTML file generated from the bluetooth transfer:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><a href="http://www.androidauthority.com/jelly-bean-ics-market-share-june-99102/">http://www.androidauthority.com/jelly-bean-ics-market-share-june-99102/</a></body></html>
```

What **I would prefer** is to have it instead, open up the URL on the default browser. My downloads folder is now filled with **bluetooth_content_share.html** files due to my transfers and I'd like to keep it clean now.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you heard of the app Pocket?

Comment: Does it have to be bluetooth? If not see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/sharing-browser-links-between-pc-and-phone

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as roxan: Go to the market (oops, playstore) and look for an app named [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) (formerly known as "ReadItLater"). This allows you to store URLs from many apps via the share menu to your free Pocket account.

As for your PC, there is e.g. a [Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/read-it-later/) available (for alternative choices, see the [Pocket website](http://getpocket.com/). This is much more convenient than sharing via Bluetooth.

Comment: I've known about Pocket and I'm actually using it. The thing is, it requires LAN connection whereas a bluetooth approach would be solely just between the computer and the phone.

Comment: That wasn't a problem for me yet, as both (computer and phone) even share the same LAN (phone via WiFi). But sorry, then I have to pass it on -- I don't know another approach.

Answer (score 0):

First use a browser that can download the current page/HTML file. Then using a file manager of your choice, use the "Share" option and it should send the HTML file.